# How do I get the depth of a URL using PHP?

Tags: php, url, path

I'd like to echo the depth (or number of directories from my home) of my current page's URL using PHP. How would I do that?

For example, if I'm on mysite.com, the output displays "0", if I'm on mysite.com/recipes, the output displays "1", and if I'm on mysite.com/recipes/pies, the output displays "2", and so on.

How do I do that?

I tried simplifying it and doing this, but it's exporting as 0:

```
$folder_depth = substr_count($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] , "/");
echo $folder_depth;
```

Comment: count number of `/` before `?`?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here is my cheap and cheezy solution using PHP's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and its `PHP_URL_PATH` return value along with a couple of other functions:

```
$url = 'http://universeofscifi.com/content/tagged/model/battlestar_galactica.html';
echo var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
echo count(explode('/', (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)))) - 2;
```

This returns:

```
string(47) "/content/tagged/model/battlestar_galactica.html"
3
```

I subtract 2 from the count to discard the domain at the front and the file at the end, leaving only the directory depth count.

Answer (score 1):

If you won't have a query string, you can explode on /. If you will have a query string, you need to remove that first, such as...

```
$url = preg_replace('/?.*$/','',$url);
```

If you have http:// or https:// at the front of your URL, that can mess it up also. So remove it...

```
$url = preg_replace('~^https*://~','',$url);
```

Now, you only have the url as example.com/some/path/to/something. You can explode on / and get a count:

```
$a = explode('/',$url);
```

The size of $a will be 1 more than what you want. So, you need to subtract one:

$depth = sizeof($a)-1;

New problem... I just counted the file itself, such as example.com/links.html will come up as 1, not just 0. So, before the explode I need to get rid of the file name. But... how do I know if it is a file or a directory? That isn't built into the URL specification. For example, example.com/test could be a file or it could be a directory (and then it automatically goes to example.com/test/index.html). You need to assume what file extensions you will have and remove those files before you explode, such as:

```
$url = preg_replace('~/[^/]+.(html|php|gig|png|mp3)$~','',$url);
```

Comment: Couldn't you also use `parse_url()` and do the math on the path?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, if you want to do it the boring way without any of the regex fun.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ heh!

Answer (score 0):

@kainaw, I like your answer! Thanks!

I took a spin on that. First, I noticed I was using the wrong PHP function to get the part of the URL I needed. Second, I needed to use @kaniaw's example and  get the parts of the URL which I'm supposed to count, and ignore the others.

I also had to account for urls without content between the "/", so something like /word//// would still count as 1. Therefore, I only counted array elements after explode() which were not empty.

Here's my code:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//echo "*".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."*";
//$url = preg_replace('/?.*$/','',$url);
//$url = preg_replace('~^https*://~','',$url);
//$url = preg_replace('~/[^/]+.(html|php|gig|png|mp3)$~','',$url);
$a = explode('/',$url);

$depth =count(array_filter($a));
echo $depth;
```

I commented out some of those lines because I didn't seen them, but they were mentioned above.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use $url=preg_replace('~/+~','/',$url); to replace ///// with a single /. It replaces any run of multiple /'s with just one /.